# Where do I propose a question?  A follow-up to a feature request?

Tags: discussion

I thought I was supposed to go to area51.stackexchange.com to ask a sample question and see if people liked it or not, but I'm not actually seeing that functionality on that page.  It seems like a place to propose topic ideas for the stackexchange.  Am I mistaken?  Does a question proposal site not exist?  I don't like getting thumbs-downed, so I want to propose my question before asking it, especially at the heavy-downer sites in the network.

-Edit-

Additional details: I would like to ask a follow-up question for a feature request.  Where's the best place?

Comment: If it's about the Stack Exchange engine/all sites, you're in the right place. If it's about a certain Stack Exchange site, go to that Meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Area 51 is for proposing and creation of a site, not seperate questions. If you are not sure if a question is a best fit for a site, see if there is an active chat site for the room and ask if the question is on-topic for that site. Also, see the [sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to give you a better idea of what sites are currently on the SE network. If there is a question you want to ask and there's no suitable site then you could always head back over to Area 51 and propose the site.

Saying that...what is the question about?

Comment: So, I have to wait like 20 minutes, but I'm thinking about posting a follow-up to a feature request that asks about a more flexible version of the feature: a toggle.  Is that 'duplicate'?  I want to get some attention and have some real answers, so I feel like a simple comment isn't enough, you know?  I've already seen some people get closed for duplicating, though.

Comment: You could post an answer to the feature request explaining your alternative. If it's already been status-declined then it might bring it back to front page and get it some more attention and see if peoples reaction is positive or negative.

Comment: Do you think that would be better than posting it as its own question?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 I think you'd be OK to post it as its own question, just reference the old one and say why yours is different.  http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com is the place to propose Area51 features, or you can do so here on MSO.

Comment: @Mat Okay.  If you are interested, it's http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109292/part-2-line-numbers-for-code-blocks-how-about-a-toggle-feature.

Answer (score 2):

There's no site for proposing questions for sites that already exist in the Stack Exchange Network.  You should read the FAQ for the site where your question seems most on-topic before posting to find out if it will be acceptable.

> It seems like a place to propose topic ideas for the stackexchange.

That's correct, [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) is for proposing topic ideas for new sites.  Once a topic is proposed, people can go to that proposal and suggest questions that they think would be on-topic for that site, but question proposals end once the site definition phase is over.

Answer (score 1):

> Does a question proposal site not exist?

I think you misunderstand something. There is no "question proposal site", Area51 is, as you noticed, only for site proposals.

If you've got a question and you're not sure where it belongs, ask on the targets Meta-Site if it is On-Topic there. If it is not On-Topic on that site, people will try to find you a fitting place for your question (if possible).

> I don't like getting thumbs-downed...

Get used to it. No, really. That's no sarcastic `you'll never write a good question/answer` but rather a `we all get downvotes`. I have 8k rep here, and I have posted some really dumb stuff which I deserved the downvotes for. I've also posted good stuff which was downvoted because people disagreed (that's legal on Meta, by the way, [see the FAQ on that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)). It's part of the whole thing, there's nothing bad about it as long as you also get upvotes.

> ...especially at the heavy-downer sites in the network.

No, not really.

Comment: AHhhhhhh!!!!  Hehe.  Just kidding.  Thanks.